# Split CSV String to multiple strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, csv

I have string like below.

```
$s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,77,88,99";
```

I want this to be split into 3 strings where

```
$s1 = "1,2,3,4"
$s2 = "5,6,77,88"
$s3 = "99"
```

I actually have a string containing close to 1000 numbers all separated by comma, I need it to be split into multiples of 400 if there are more than 400 values separated by comma within the string.

Comment: Please try to elaborate on what you actually want to do here. Do you want your csv string to be split up in multiple lines of 4 numbers? What?

Comment: I want csv string to be split into multiple strings where each string contains 4 numbers separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can `explode` it as array and use of `array_chunk` function to split by size:

```
$array = explode(',', $csv_string);
$array_chunks = array_chunk($array, 400);
```

If you want to add comma between them use below code:

```
$array = explode(',', $csv_string);
$array_chunks = array_chunk($array, 400);
$array_strings = array_map(function($item) { 
    return implode(',', $item);
}, $array_chunks);
```